# Format number in jsp

Tags: jsp, number-formatting

How do I format an int value of `123456789` as `123,456,789`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
public class Main {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###");
    System.out.print(formatter.format(123456789));
}
```

}

you can write a function in jsp block <%! %> and the code inside the main method.

Comment: Try not to use scriptlets <% %> in modern applications. Use JSTL where possible.

Answer (score 16):

Use JSTL fmt:formatNumber

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatNumber.html

Set your pattern to #,##0

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<fmt:formatNumber pattern="#,##0" value="${value}" />
```

This will require you having The JSTL Standard tag library in your WEB-INF/lib folder

http://tomcat.apache.org/taglibs/standard/

Now I'm not 100% sure, but most modern containers provide the "core" API library jstl.jar and your web app must provide the implemenation. In the case of the above link that should be standard.jar included with the download.

Comment: Hi I tried your answer but I'm getting an error "The absolute uri http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt cannot be resolved in either web.xml or jar..."

Comment: Sorry I had assumed you had JSTL added to your web app.

Comment: @DaveG: Your pattern needs to be corrected. Currently it is '#,###0' and should be '#,##0'.

Comment: Dunno, I am getting `javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected '0' in pattern "#,##0"`

Comment: Which JSTL are you using? can you provide details? I just built out a sample application and it worked fine. I can post that to github if you like.

Comment: Uploaded a repo on github - https://github.com/djgraff209/stackoverflow-5508063 enjoy

Answer (score 0):

NumberFormat: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html